# Hot to update Ubuntu Server packages with yum update?

Tags: server, updates

After booting and logging in, the message "xx updates available, xx updates are security updates". I type `yum update` and I am informed that it needs to be installed? Yum is not installed as part of the Base OS? Why does the system not start in GUI? Is this going to be fixed in next release? Server 12.x

Comment: Debian based Linux such as Ubuntu does not use `yum` that's a Red Hat/Fedora thing use **apt-get** instead.  Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo aptr-get upgrade`  If you get any errors edit the question to tell us what they are.  Otherwise your done. The server version does not come with a GUI but you can install one.

Comment: Servers generally come without a GUI.

Answer (score 4):

Yum is a package manager for RPM-based systems - for Debian-based systems such as Ubuntu you will use the `apt` system e.g.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The Ubuntu server editions are pure servers - if you want a GUI, install one of the desktop editions instead, or install the desktop of your choice on top of the server base via apt-get e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed the Ubuntu 12.04 Server , It will Start in Full user mode that mean i  used to start in Run level 3 , we cant access in GUI , Use command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To get the latest updates

Server version all comes in Run level 3 in CLI mode if u need in GUI you need to install cinnamon from PPA repository